# Replacing data from one column in a table with another using an unrelated tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on updating an existing system which will display a table on a web from to show who has called out of work. The data is pulled from a database consisting of two tables. One contains the actual data recorded from the call, and the other is a 'Legend' of sorts so convert a single digit in a column to a plain text description. For example:

```
Options Table

|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      LevelName      |     OptionNo     |    Description   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         LorA        |         1        |       Late       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         LorA        |         2        |      Absent      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         TorT        |         1        |       Today      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         TorT        |         2        |     Tomorrow     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

The second table has a layout like this (only showing relevant fields):

```
CallData Table

|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     EmployeeName    |  Todaytomorrow   |  Late_Or_Absent  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         John        |         1        |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         Jane        |         2        |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

What I am having trouble with is how to somehow relate the two tables in order to replace the integer representation in the CallLog Table with the corresponding value in the Options Table.

I have tried creating a temporary table by selecting all from both tables, however when I attempt to replace the values only those which happen to align after the join are replaced.

Here is the SQL I currently have:

```
/*Create TempTable to be updated*/
 SELECT * INTO #tempStore FROM CallData, [Options]
 WHERE CallData.EmpName IS NOT NULL AND call_completed = '1'

 /*Query Pertinant Info*/
 SELECT [CallinID], [EmpName], [TodayTomorrow] AS [When], [Late_Or_Absent] AS [Type], [Late_Reason] AS [Reason], 
 [Absent_Reason], [Early_Reason], [Contact_Number], [Comment], [created_dt] FROM [#tempStore]

 /*Update Type to varChar*/
 ALTER TABLE [#tempStore]
 ALTER COLUMN [TodayTomorrow] nvarchar(20)

  /*Perform TorT Update*/
 UPDATE [#tempStore] SET [#tempStore].TodayTomorrow = [#tempStore].[Description]
 WHERE [#tempStore].LevelName = 'TorT' AND [#tempStore].TodayTomorrow = CONVERT(nvarchar(1), [#tempStore].[OptionNo])
```

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For this example, I think the following will work:

```
select  cd.EmployeeName
        ,optTT.Description TodayTomorrow
        ,optLE.Description Late_or_Absent
from    CallData as cd
join    [Options] as optTT on optTT.OptionNo = cd.Late_or_Absent and optTT.LevelName = 'TorT'
join    [Options] as optLE on optLE.OptionNo = cd.TodayTomorrow and optLE.LevelName = 'LorA'
```

Edited: added joining on different levels. If there are more than two levels, a more general solution is required.

Comment: I would agree with you, however this solution breaks down because the OptionNo can be the same for a number of different LevelNames. In the example CallData table above, John has two number, however the OptionNo will only match to one.

Comment: Right, I missed that. So TorT refers to column TodayTomorrow, and LorA refers to Late_or_Absent? Do you want to replace both of them with descriptions?

Comment: I had considered an option similar to this, however I don't see how it would be any more effective than hard coding an update into the temporary table for each of these levels. There are 5 different fields each employee has that fit this same design.